# What's the best way to create a mask knowing the number of bits?

Tags: verilog

If I know the number of bits for a field, what's the best way to create a mask for that field.

For example, if number of bits is 4, I want a mask `4'b1111`

I'm currently doing C-style mask creation:

```
`define MY_BITS 4
...
mask = (1 << `MY_BITS) - 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the replication operator:

```
mask = {`MY_BITS{1'b1}};
```

Alternative (System-Verilog only):

```
logic [`MY_BITS-1:0] mask;
...
mask = '1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the replication operator:

```
mask = {`MY_BITS{1'b1}};
```

See http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators2.html for some examples.